# Draw the memory image view with python

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, draw

I want to draw a rectangle of a process memory image. Making unmapped memory as black, mapped memory bytes as green, and highlight the sensitive bytes with red. Similar to the following figure. The x-axis is the address from base 0 to the memory image length, the y-axis can be 16 bytes memory width. Any idea how to draw it?

[image]